# Как оставить в тексте фрагменты по шаблону?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть некий набор символов (текст). В нем встречаются последовательности типа [start /*набор символов*/ end]. Необходимо в другую переменную вывести все такие конструкции с содержимым. Т.е. получается: 
"[start /*набор символов1*/ end][start /*набор символов2*/ end][start /*набор символов3*/ end]".

Подозреваю, что делать надо через регулярные выражения, но умею только делать проверку на соответствие. А вот искать с их помощью не получается.

Comment: посмотрите в сторону [preg_split()][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, приблизительно такой принцип:

```
$pattern = "|begin(.*?)end|si";// доработайте регулярное выражение как вам нужно, а //то я не силён в них
$str = "begin слово1 end";
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $m))
    print_r($m);
```

В помощь есть не плохой онлайн сервис по регулярным выражениям с flash интерфейсом
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/